# Value not Inserted in a table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on WPF. There are two problems generated in my code.

1. when i entered values it assigned 0 to ID
2. secondly after inserting value when I stopped debugging 
     and again started it, it showed value of Id but it didn't 
     show entered value. and assigned 1005 rather than assigning 12.

Please guide me.

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko Sir please view my question here! Thank You

Comment: In my opinion your ID column is marked as an identity column in the database. It means its values are generated automatically - so everything is working as expected. You can change this setting if you want to generate the IDs by hand (if you really need it).

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko yes sir  ID column is marked as an identity column in the database but i don't want to change its setting, how can i solve my first issue that is it inserts value but if i debug it again, it doesn't show any inserted value.

Comment: you should attach more information to this post e.g. code, screenshots etc. Debug carefully through your code, check values of your data - are all members of the object you're trying to save really initialized properly? Be sure transaction is already committed while you shut down debug mode etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have IDENTITY on ID column in table,maybe IDENTITY value is 1005 ?
If that is case you could RESEED value in table with DBCC CHECKIDENT